# Order the output of ls command based on the name of the files and in the order they arrived

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have a file with below content that is output from a ls -lrt command.
It's a big file that contains ls -lrt output for few months.

```
sh>  ls -lrt /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/2020*/*/*{GNMDCONS,GMFDAILY,GMFDLYMNI,FHLSEC1D,FNMSEC1D,FHLSUP1D,FNMSUP1D,FNMDUSDN,GNMHECD,FNMSEC1M,FHLSEC1M,FHLSEC2M,FHLSEC3M,FHLPSEC4M,FNMSUP1M,FHLSUP1M,FHLSUP2M,FHLSUP3M,FHLPSUP4M,FNMDUSMBS,GNMISS2,G11FCTR,G21FCTR,GNMHECM,GMFMON,GNMMCONS,G12FCTR,G22FCTR,FNMGMEGA,FHLGGNT,GNMPDSCL,FNMDUSDC,FNMDUSMC}.*
```

A file has two parts: a ZIP file and a SIG file. They get downloaded with different time stamps.

```
sh> head /tmp/jan_files -n14
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      1541 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    191881 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     23185 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDLYMNI.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        30 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDLYMNI.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      7726 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:39:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:40:18
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    185206 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:40:38
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     11179 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:44:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:45:37
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:41:21
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    282086 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:45:59
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:46:44
sh>
```

I am trying to create an output that pairs the ZIP and SIG file together based on the time they arrived like below.

```
sh> head /tmp/jan_files -n14
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      1541 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    191881 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     23185 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDLYMNI.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        30 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDLYMNI.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      7726 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:39:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:40:18
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    185206 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:40:38
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:41:21
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     11179 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:44:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:45:37
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    282086 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:45:59
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:46:44
sh>
```

I have created the below sort command which is close but its not what I am looking for.

```
sh> sort -s -k6M -k7n -b -k8.1,8.2 -k9.42,9.43 -k9.51,9.52 /tmp/jan_files | head -n14
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      1541 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     23185 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDLYMNI.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    191881 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        30 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDLYMNI.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      7726 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:39:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    185206 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:40:38
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     11179 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:44:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    282086 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:45:59
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:40:18
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:41:21
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:45:37
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:46:44
sh>
```

Update:

Another case of input files

```
sh-4.1$ head /tmp/jan_files
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2163 Jan  3 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:24 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239840 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13560 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:43:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    207324 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:44:23
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:44:58
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:44:04
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8525 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:38:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:39:31
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:39:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:40:25
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.15:39:11
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.15:40:10
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.15:40:47
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.15:39:51
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13958 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.15:43:55
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    212215 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.15:44:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.15:44:32
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.15:45:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     16340 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239708 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2513 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP.20:00:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5286 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP.20:01:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG.20:02:30
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG.20:01:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      3249 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5951 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG
sh-4.1$
```

A vendor creates certain files everyday. Below are the list of files.  {GNMDCONS,GMFDAILY,GMFDLYMNI,FHLSEC1D,FNMSEC1D,FHLSUP1D,FNMSUP1D,FNMDUSDN,GNMHECD,FNMSEC1M,FHLSEC1M,FHLSEC2M,FHLSEC3M,FHLPSEC4M,FNMSUP1M,FHLSUP1M,FHLSUP2M,FHLSUP3M,FHLPSUP4M,FNMDUSMBS,GNMISS2,G11FCTR,G21FCTR,GNMHECM,GMFMON,GNMMCONS,G12FCTR,G22FCTR,FNMGMEGA,FHLGGNT,GNMPDSCL,FNMDUSDC,FNMDUSMC}
Each file has two parts: a ZIP file and a SIG file. The problem is that they get downloaded with different timestamps. I am trying to pair them together based on the time that they get downloaded. I will then use that list for another operation that will load these file into a database. The load operation requires both the ZIP file and it's associated SIG file. Also, when the same file arrives multiple times a day, it gets renamed with timestamp appended to the file name.

I am looking for output something like this.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2163 Jan  3 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:24 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239840 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8525 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:38:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:39:31
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:39:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:40:25
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13560 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:43:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:44:04
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    207324 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:44:23
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:44:58
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.15:39:11
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.15:39:51
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.15:40:10
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.15:40:47
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13958 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.15:43:55
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.15:44:32
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    212215 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.15:44:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.15:45:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     16340 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239708 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2513 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP.20:00:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG.20:01:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5286 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP.20:01:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG.20:02:30
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      3249 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5951 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG
```

This is what my sort outputs

```
sh-4.1$ sort -s -k6M -k7n -b -k8.1,8.2 -k9.42,9.43 -k9.51,9.52 /tmp/jan_files
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2163 Jan  3 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239840 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:24 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8525 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:38:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:39:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13560 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:43:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    207324 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:44:23
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:39:31
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:40:25
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:44:58
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:44:04
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.15:39:11
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.15:40:10
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13958 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.15:43:55
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    212215 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.15:44:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.15:40:47
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.15:39:51
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.15:44:32
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.15:45:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     16340 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239708 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2513 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP.20:00:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5286 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP.20:01:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG.20:02:30
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG.20:01:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      3249 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5951 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG
sh-4.1$
```

And this is what your solution outputs

```
sh-4.1$ awk  -F"[/.]" '{print $2,$9,$8" |"$0}' /tmp/jan_files | \
> sort -k5,5M -k6,6n -k7,7 -k8,9                   | \
> awk  -F"|" '{print $2}'
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2163 Jan  3 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:24 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239840 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 05:34 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13560 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:43:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    207324 Jan  3 06:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:44:23
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:44:04
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:44:58
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8525 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:38:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:39:31
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:39:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:40:25
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.15:39:11
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 11:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.15:40:10
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.15:39:51
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.15:40:47
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     13958 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.15:43:55
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.15:44:32
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    212215 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.15:44:50
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 11:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.15:45:28
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    174536 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     16340 Jan  3 15:30 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      8537 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:31 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    239708 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      2513 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP.20:00:56
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5286 Jan  3 15:55 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP.20:01:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG.20:01:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 15:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG.20:02:30
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      3249 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSDN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSDN.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      5951 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Products/FNMDUSMN.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  3 19:56 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200103/Signal/FNMDUSMN.SIG
sh-4.1$
```

Comment: what are you expecting for output when a pair of 'matching' files have OS timestamps that differ by 1+ second(s), eg: `05:23 and 05:25` or `05:59 and 06:00`?

Comment: the 4x files @ 05:39 are not sorted alphabetically, while the 6x files a@ 06:33 are sorted alphabetically ... typo? or some other/odd sorting logic?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @markp I have made an update to the question which I hope answers your questions.

Comment: you need to define (in text) the rules you're trying to implement in your sort; I spent too much time last night trying to *guess* at what you're looking for; maybe someone else will come along who has some free time on his/her hands to try and glean a pattern from the wall of sample `ls` listings ...

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- `time they arrived` is referring to the OS timestamp on the file (eg, `Jan 2 05:23`), and not the timestamp suffix that some files have
- the OS timestamp has precedence when sorting files which means ...
- 'matching' files will have the same OS timestamp (eg, 05:23 == 05:23) otherwise the proposed sorting method may not group matching files together [NOTE: this assumption is pretty flimsy since there are going to be 'matching' files with OS timestamps that differ by 1+ seconds which in turn causes a 1-minute difference, eg: 05:23:59+1 second => 05:24]
- for a set of files with the same OS timestamp the sorting preference is by parent directory (`{Products,Signal}`) and then filename, both alphabetically (which means the files in the sample output with OS timestamp of `05:39` are not sorted properly)

Sample data:

```
$ cat jan_files
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      1541 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    191881 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     23185 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDLYMNI.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        30 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDLYMNI.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      7726 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:39:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:40:18
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    185206 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:40:38
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     11179 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:44:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:45:37
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:41:21
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    282086 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:45:59
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:46:44
```

The general idea is to pull a copy of the sortable fields to the front of the line, with a copy of the original line appended on the end; once we perform the desired sorts we strip off the 'sort fields' and we're left with our original lines in the desired sort order.

Here's one `awk/sort/awk` combo:

```
awk  -F"[/.]" '{print $2,$9,$8" |"$0}' jan_files | \
sort -k5,5M -k6,6n -k7,7 -k8,9                   | \
awk  -F"|" '{print $2}'
```

Where:

- first `awk` command uses dual delimiters (`\` and `.`) and reprints fields 2 (owner/group/timestamp) and the last 2 fields (`{Products,Signal}` and the base/filename), followed by a new delimiter (`|`) and the entire line; this allows us to (more) easily sort by all the desired fields and still keep our entire line intact ...
- the `sort` command allows us to sort by Month, Day, HH:MM, `{Products,Signal}` and filename; with appropriate flags to allow us to sort as per the desired output
- second `awk` makes use of our new delimiter (`|`) to allow us to strip off our 'sort fields' and display the original line

Running the above on the sample data file

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      1541 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDAILY.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:23 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDAILY.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     23185 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GMFDLYMNI.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        30 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GMFDLYMNI.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    191881 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/GNMDCONS.ZIP
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 05:39 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/GNMDCONS.SIG
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg      7726 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSEC1D.ZIP.11:39:35
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:32 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSEC1D.SIG.11:40:18
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    185206 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FHLSUP1D.ZIP.11:40:38
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FHLSUP1D.SIG.11:41:21
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg     11179 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSEC1D.ZIP.11:44:54
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSEC1D.SIG.11:45:37
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg    282086 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Products/FNMSUP1D.ZIP.11:45:59
-rw-r--r--. 1 ctlr sftg        29 Jan  2 06:33 /vdat/sfrdir/mkbs/daily/20200102/Signal/FNMSUP1D.SIG.11:46:44
```

Comment: What a marvelous answer!

Comment: You don't need a \ after `|`. If `|` is the last character in the line, then newlines (and lines with a comment) are ignored.